# TAR override the contents of the directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix, tar

My understanding of tar command that it will override the content of the file if file exist. Otherwise it would keep as existing.

```
[root@something~]# ls -al /etc/init.d/
total XX
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    83 Jun 14  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root   127 Jun  6  2017 ..
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root  7293 Jan  2  2018 network
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1160 Feb 20  2018 README
[root@something~]# tar tvf /tmp/env_pkg_1.tar 
drwxr-xr-x staff    0 2020-05-29 19:42 etc/
drwxr-xr-x user/staff    0 2020-05-29 18:04 etc/init.d/
-rw-r--r-- user/staff 3383 2020-05-29 18:04 etc/init.d/sshd
[root@something~]# cd /
[root@something /]# tar xf /tmp/env_pkg_1.tar 
[root@something/]# ls -al /etc/init.d/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x   2 XXXXXX XXXXXX 18 May 29 18:04 .
drwxr-xr-x. 85 XXXXXX XXXXXX 8192 May 29 19:42 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 XXXXXX XXXXXX 3383 May 29 18:04 sshd
```

I am not understand why tar is replacing the entire contents of /etc/init.d

Any inputs would be helpful ?

Comment: Hi interesting, perhaps you were in the root directory `[root@something /] # tar xf` when you untarred the package? It will create the files relative to the current directory.

Comment: I had moved to / (by cd /). Update the code sections above as well.

Comment: You can use `-v` to get verbose output, might have some more clues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive that `/etc/init.d` is a link to `/etc/rc.d/init.d`.

When you untarred that file, it overwrote the link with a directory.  All of your files are still in `/etc/rc.d/init.d`.

To fix your situation, remove `/etc/init.d`, relink it, and add a `h` to the tar command:

```
rm -rf /etc/init.d
cd /etc
ln -s ./rc.d/init.d
cd /
tar xhf /tmp/env_pkg_1.tar
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, it is the only explanation because tar doesn't follow symlinks by default

Answer (score 0):

You can use `-k` or `--keep-old-files`, so it does not touch any files that are already within the destination. Judging by your output in `/etc/init.d/` you want to keep `network` and `README` and next to them extract `sshd`, so in your case, they do not overlap.

Alternatively `--keep-newer-files` will have tar replace files that are newer from the tar archive, than what's on the destination..

Comment: The `--keep-old-files` flag will work as intended, but with `--keep-newer-files`, `tar` will still overwrite the existing softlink (`init.d -> rc.d/init.d`) with a directory if the directory in the tar file is newer than the link.

Comment: That is why you have `--keep-directory-symlink`. Is this why you downvoted me???

Comment: Yes, it is. The symlink is the problem.  Fix it and I'll upvote!

Comment: My version of `tar` has `--dereference` or `-h`. (Fedora)